# Splitting a prolog list based on a delimiter from the list?

Tags: prolog, declarative

In Prolog, let's say I have a list such as

```
[fun, joke1, joke2, fun, joke3, fun, joke4, joke5, joke6]
```

I'm trying to build a list of lists that will result to

```
[ [joke1, joke2], [joke4, joke5, joke6] ]
```

using fun as the delimiter and ignoring a built list of length 1, hence

```
[joke3]
```

is not inside that list.

I tried using split_string but it doesn't work for what I need to obtain. I've also tried recursion using append but that didn't work out as well. Hoping I can be pointed to the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses two predicates:

```
split_on_delimiter(L, D, S) :-
    split_on_delimiter_(L, D, R),
    findall(X, (member(X, R), length(X,Length), Length > 1), S).

split_on_delimiter_([], _, [[]]).    
split_on_delimiter_([D|T], D, [[]|T2]) :-
    split_on_delimiter_(T, D, T2).
split_on_delimiter_([H|T], D, [[H|T2]|T3]) :-
    dif(H, D),
    split_on_delimiter_(T, D, [T2|T3]).
```

`split_on_delimiter_/3` is the predicate which really splits the list based on the delimiter `D`. `split_on_delimiter/3` is the predicate that you would call and which will in turn call `split_on_delimiter_/3`.

To keep only the sublists of length more than 1, we use `findall` to find all sublists of the result of the split which have `Length > 1`.

`split_on_delimiter_/3` itself is fairly simple:

- First rule: spliting an empty list results in only one sublist: the empty list.
- Second rule: when the first element of the list is the delimiter, the result is the empty list followed by the result of the recursive call.
- Third rule: when the first element of the list is not the delimiter (`dif(H, D)`), then we put that element at the beginning of the first sublist and recursive call.

#### An example:

```
?- split_on_delimiter([fun, joke1, joke2, fun, joke3, fun, joke4, joke5, joke6], fun, Z).
Z = [[joke1, joke2], [joke4, joke5, joke6]] ;
false.
```

#### Note

`split_on_delimiter_/3` has extraneous choice points (which is why you can press `;` after the first result, because it thinks there can be more answers but there are none). You could solve this using `!` or `once`.

A better solution to remove those choice points is using `if_/3` and `(=)/3` of [`module(reif)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) (though I doubt this is useful to you):

```
split_on_delimiter_(L, D, [L2|T2]) :-
    if_(L = [],
        [L2|T2] = [[]],
        (   L = [H|T],
            if_(H = D,
                (   L2 = [],
                    split_on_delimiter_(T, D, T2)
                ),
                (   L2 = [H|T3],
                    split_on_delimiter_(T, D, [T3|T2])
                )
            )
        )
    ).
```

Comment: That's a really good answer Fatalize. Thank you for helping me understand my problem, appreciate it!

Comment: There's actually one thing that bugs me though: I can't use maplist on split_on_delimiter, even after using !. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: @JonTan What do you mean? Using maplist with the same delimiter everytime? If that's the ccase simply change the head of `split_on_delimiter/3` to `split_on_delimiter(D, L, S)`, so that the delimiter is first and that you can call it as such: `maplist(split_on_delimiter(D), Ls, Ss)`.

Comment: s(X) for the note **only**!

Comment: Your original definition succeeds for `split_on_delimiter([a,B],d,[[a,c]]),B=b.` and fails for `B=b,split_on_delimiter([a,B],d,[[a,c]]).` So efficiency is not the biggest problem.

Comment: In systems like SICStus, `( Xs = [], Nimporte_0 ; Xs = [_|_], Quelconque_0 )` will be determinate if possible. Only SWI needs `if_(Xs = [], Nimporte_0, ...)` to avoid the CP.

Comment: `member(X, R), length(X,Length), Length > 1` better replaced by `X = [_,_|_], member(X, R)`

Comment: There's actually one problem I think I have. Though this works usually, if the list in L is made up of logical variables, findall will not return me the same variables. setof and bagof will work but if L has more than 1 list, it will only care about the first 1. Is there a way to either make findall return the same logical variables as indicated in L or could I make setof work like findall?

Comment: @JonTan: Your observation is accurate. The safest way to avoid issues with copied variables, is to avoid copying them altogether. `setof/3` and `bagof/3` try to hide them, but once you are using constraints, the ugly problems reappear. Therefore stick to the version in the Notes!